# Strange Issue Validating Empty Text Box in Winforms .NET 4.0 VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, validation

I am just adding validation into a new winform. I am using the **validating** and **validated** events, in conjunction with an **error provider** control. Please see code below.

No problem with first validation (ie. if user enters more than 12 characters). Error is set in validating event, and error stays until user enters 12 or less characters. **Validated** event is then entered and error is reset to empty string.

However, there is a problem with the 2nd validation on same text box. The code checks for zero length in text box.. and sets error with provider. Watching in the debugger, this code is indeed invoked, and error is set ok. Then something weird happens, the **validated** event is *(unexpectedly)* fired, and the code there promptly resets the error.

Why is the **validated** event fired when there is already an error set ? This seems like a .NET bug. Can anyone suggest another way of doing this, or say what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks,

Bazza

```
Private Sub SampleCodeTextBox_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles SampleCodeTextBox.Validating
    If SampleCodeTextBox.Text.Length > 12 Then
        e.Cancel = True
        FormErrorProvider.SetError(SampleCodeTextBox, "Max of 12 characters for sample code")
    End If

    If SampleCodeTextBox.Text.Trim.Length = 0 Then
        FormErrorProvider.SetError(SampleCodeTextBox, "Must enter a sample code")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SampleCodeTextBox_Validated(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SampleCodeTextBox.Validated
    FormErrorProvider.SetError(SampleCodeTextBox, "")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` property to `True` when your zero-length Text check fails in your Validating event handler.

From the MSDN article on the [Control.Validated Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated.aspx):

> If the Cancel property of the CancelEventArgs is set to true in the
>   Validating event delegate, all events that would usually occur after
>   the Validating event are suppressed.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you missing `e.Cancel = True` in the next if block?